# Loading raster on PostgreSQL/PostGIS Linux server not working

Tags: qgis, postgis, raster, postgresql, raster2pgsql

I used the following raster2pgsql.exe to upload an SRTM mosaic to my Linux database server (working fine for vector data):

```
raster2pgsql.exe -I -t auto e:\data\Sinai\SRTM90V41b\SRTM41M90.tif SRTM90c | psql -d Sinai-U postgis -h 179.19.1.27 -p 5432
```

The process is carried out smoothly, however, when I open the DB Manager in QGIS, I'm unable to preview the Public.SRTM90c raster, and if I try to add it to QGIS, I get this message:

Invalid Layer: Raster layer Cannot instantiate the 'postgresraster' data provider

Any clues?

Comment: which version of QGIS do you have?

Comment: Which version of PostGIS do you have?

Comment: Thank you for responding: Version 3.0